# Visual Studio, MS Build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am trying to build multiple .sln files inside a batch file. Everything works great so far. I am trying to add a check inside the batch file, so if number of errors is greater than 0 then the batch file stops executing and doesn't build the next .sln files. How can I do that? Basically something like:

msbuild test.sln
(check if build error > 0
stop)
msbuild test2.sln

Answer (score 4):

MSBUILD will set the ERRORLEVEL, so something along the lines of:

```
msbuild test.sln
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 exit 1
```

Edit: Apparently it should be:

```
msbuild test.sln
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 exit 1
```

Comment: "not errorlevel 0" is always false, as "errorlevel 0" always true.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. MSBuild always returns an errorlevel of 0 regardless of whether there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
msbuild.exe test.sln
if errorlevel 1 goto :errors

msbuild.exe test2.sln
if errorlevel 1 goto :errors

:: ...

:: Everything was fine.
echo Build completed without errors.
goto :eof

:error
echo Build failed.
```

Comment: I'm not sure it always returns 1? Not 0 might be safer

Comment: if errorlevel 1 

will be true if errorlevel is 1 or _higher_:

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
                    returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number
                    specified.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's much easier to use a custom msbuild file here and use the msbuild task with your set of solutions. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) for the details.